# MultiChannel or MultiLegder Hyperledger Fabric Configuration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Does anyone have a sample,

**How to configure a multichannel hyperledger fabric network?**

The setup should include:

1. One CA
2. One Orders
3. 4 Peers
4. 4 Channels

And trust model as following:

- Peer0 ( Access to all the channels)
- Peer1(Access to Channel 1 and Channel2)
- Peer2(Access to Channel 1 and Channel3)
- Peer3(Access to Channel 1 and Channel4)

Comment: How many organization you are going to have?

Comment: @Artem Barger 3 Org

Comment: Can you specify how peers are associated with those 3 orgs?

Comment: @ArtemBarger I am planning to have 1 peer for each org

Comment: So in your question you are planning for 4 peers and for channels, I am a bit confused

Comment: @ArtemBarger: Basically we need 4 channels to hold private transaction between 2 orgs, but Channel 1 is shared channels which can be accessed across 2 orgs . That is the kind of setup which we are looking . As per my understanding this can be achieved with the help of peers. If we look into this document ( https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eRNxxQ0P8yp4Wh__Vi6ddaN_vhN2RQHP-IruHNUwyhc/edit#) there is a design how to achieve. I am looking for similar setup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162832/discussion-between-hafeez-khan-and-artem-barger).

Comment: Ping me on Rocket.Chat @c0rwin chat.hyperledger.org

Answer (score 0):

I guess each organization has per peer.
Org0(peer0), Org1(peer1), Org2(peer2), Org3(peer3)

Channel 1

- consortium: Org0, Org1

Channel 2

- consortium: Org0, Org2

Channel 3

- consortium: Org0, Org3

---

1. you have to enter orderer in per consortium.
2. you have to make configtx.yaml like https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#crypto-generator